# I cannot access model methods when using DB Facade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this model and I don't want to use eloquent due to some performance and slow query, even though I'm using Eager Loading the performance changes little bit. But unlike DB Facade the query is much faster. My problem is how can I access the method inside my model by using DB Facade?

```
----------------------
    Table: user
    id | fname | lname
-----------------------
```

and this is my model

```
class User extends Model {
    public function complete_name() {
       return $this->fname . " ".$this->lname;
    }
}
```

but when Im using

```
$users = DB::table('user')->get();
```

and loop through it

```
$result = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
     $result[] = $user->complete_name();
    }
return $result;
```

I cannot access the method "complete_name()". Is there any techniques or style in order for me to access the method inside User class?

Comment: Query builder does not use or return Models (it returns `stdClass` objects, not models) ... Eloquent is the models and ORM, you have to use the models to get models

Answer (score 1):

your model User.php

```
class User extends Model {

   public function complete_name() {
      return $this->fname . " ".$this->lname;
   }

}
```

You can also use like this

```
use App\User;

$users = User::all();
```

Then You can access your complete_name() method.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $result[] = $user->complete_name();
}
return $result;
```

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to use laravel eloquent for my project special the extends model method. The metrics between DB and elequent in query more than 150K has a big difference in terms of speed. If there is any way to use DB and accessing those method

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to call the complete_name method on there, because the Query builder not return model. you can write your code like below:

```
$users = DB::table('user')->get();
```

your loop could be like:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $result[] =$user->fname.' '. $user->lname;
}
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

For using methods in model you must use eloquent instead query builder
Like first answer

otherwise

```
public function index(){

    $users = DB::table('user')->get();

    $result = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
       $result[] = $this->complete_name($user);
    }
    return $result;

}

public function complete_name($user) {
   return $user->fname . " ".$user->user;
}
```

Comment: yes, but i dont want to use laravel eloquent for my project special the extends model method. The metrics between DB and elequent in query more than 150K has a big difference in terms of speed.

Comment: an other way to user helper method you make method and pass args in the controller

Comment: see the above example